# Is there a way to 'convert' a native WinAPI Window to WinForms one?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I'm pretty sure the answer will be 'no', but I have to ask.
I don't want to use the inner controls, just the window itself.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How does this other window get created? Does it exist in the same process as your WinForms app?

Comment: Sure there's a way, but it's pretty much a re-write.

Comment: David Heffernan: Yes, it's created by a C DLL.

Comment: Is the specific requirement related to assigning Winforms application as the owner of the WIN32 window ? If yes, then `Construct an implementation of IWin32Window that wraps the IntPtr.`

Comment: Can't you just show the Window then? Why do you need to "convert", whatever that means?

Comment: David Hefferman: I can show the window, but I want to be able to use it as a WinForms Form.

Comment: That's not going to work at all.

Comment: @blez: So you mean you want to use this `WIN32 Window` such that you should be able to add controls to it in the runtime [when you say `use it as a Winforms Form`] ?  If yes, then answer is `No` [as David mentioned] if you can `tell exactly` why do you want to do this?

Comment: Angshuman Agarwal: I have a GUI toolkit, which uses WinForms, but I want to rewrite it in C so I can use it from native applications easily. The problem is that I want to wrap this in WinForms too, so I wanted an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably depends on what you want to do with it.

Even if you can't "convert" it, you can still use P/Invoke and the Windows API to do plenty of things to it.

And you might be able to do something with

```
var form = Control.FromHandle(handle) as Form;
```

if you can get the HWND of the window.

Comment: How could `FromHandle` work? That would have to perform an act of magic. If the window handle is not associated with a WinForms control, then you can't wish it otherwise.

Comment: I was hoping a top-level window might look similar enough to a form for some methods (such as setting its position, etc -- I don't know what the OP wants to do) to work. YMMV, of course.

Comment: YMMV? No, `FromHandle` will never perform that magic. No variation at all.

Comment: Fair enough. It was worth a shot though. :)

Comment: You will need to create a `IWin32Window` from a `WIN32 handle` such that it can be used in ShowDialog, specifying owner of MessageBox , etc...